# Why is jenkins not connecting to the github repository

Tags: github, jenkins, configuration

I am trying to connect to the github repository

[adding github repo link in source management here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhfLq.png)

It is not able to connect to the repository. I have even generated the personal access token for my github.

[connection to github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgR3v.png)

As you can see the connection to the github is made in jenkins system configuration. I still do not understand why the repository is not getting connected can someone pls help me?

Answer (score 0):

Test the git command outside of Jenkins on the Jenkins server's command line to see if it's able to connect to the GitHub repository.

If you are able to perform git command from Jenkins server's command line then check the Jenkins system logs for more detailed error messages that might provide insights into the issue and add the error message/image.

- To see the Jenkins system logs you need to go to Jenkins UI then click on  `Manage Jenkins -> System Log`